# How to combine Piface Relays + and Motor Control

Tags: relay, piface

I have a Raspberry, a relay plus and a motor control.
In python, I'm not able to address the both instructions at the same time.

I use : pfr ton initialize :

```
#Now initialise your Relay+.
pfr = pifacerelayplus.PiFaceRelayPlus(pifacerelayplus.MOTOR_DC)
pfr = pifacerelayplus.PiFaceRelayPlus(pifacerelayplus.RELAY)
```

Seems to be that I cannot use both instructions at the same time.
In this case only the relays work. But I can't start or stop the motor.

```
pfr.motors[1].forward()
```

But is I hash out the pfr RELAY, the motor instruction work.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You are using the variable pfr twice, so the first assignment gets lost. If you change your code to use different variable names like so:</strike>

```
pfr_motor = pifacerelayplus.PiFaceRelayPlus(pifacerelayplus.MOTOR_DC) 
pfr_relay = pifacerelayplus.PiFaceRelayPlus(pifacerelayplus.RELAY)
```

then

```
pfr_motor.motors[1].forward()
```

should work. Similarly, if you want to do something with the relay, use the pfr_relay variable.

By the way, these are very basic programming constructs (variables and object references) so make sure you get comfortable with programming in general and programming in Python in specific before attempting more complicated code.

UPDATE: I've done a quick check in [the PiFaceRelayPlus docs](http://pifacerelayplus.readthedocs.io/reference.html), and found the following example code (executed in the Python Shell):

```
>>> pfrp = pifacerelayplus.PiFaceRelayPlus(pifacerelayplus.MOTOR)
>>> pfrp.inputs[2].value
0
>>> pfrp.relays[3].turn_on()
>>> pfrp.motor[2].forward()
```

According to this example, you should only have 1 reference to your PiFaceRelayPlus (the `pfrp = ...` line). The first argument of PiFaceRelayPlus is the add-on board you used (in your case the Motor DC board). Once initialized through this assignment, you can now use the `inputs[]`, `relays[]` and `motor[]` lists to access motors and relays at the same time.

Comment: Indeed, very basic,

Comment: You need to start somewhere, tx anyway...

Comment: @ home test :Even if I use

Comment: Even if I use the different variables, it still overwrites the previous :
import pifacerelayplus
import time
# Now initialise your Relay+.
pfr_relay = pifacerelayplus.PiFaceRelayPlus(pifacerelayplus.RELAY)
pfr_motor = #pifacerelayplus.PiFaceRelayPlus(pifacerelayplus.MOTOR_DC)
while True:
    pfr_relay.relays[0].set_high()
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Pin 0 GPIO = " + str(pfr_relay.x_pins[0].value))

Comment: After reading the docs, I've updated my answer.

Comment: First of all you used : pfrp = pifacerelayplus.PiFaceRelayPlus(pifacerelayplus.MOTOR)
>>> pfrp.inputs[2].value
0
>>> pfrp.relays[3].turn_on()
>>> pfrp.motor[2].forward()

Comment: MOTOR does not work, I Need to use MOTOR_DC

Comment: I used the motor instruction in a function, and after removing the function, and put it in the code itself, it worked.